# sqlsrv_has_rows() ERROR PHP with MSSQL

Tags: php, html, sql-server-2012-express

I'm having a slight problem with my php page which I just don't understand. I'm new in this and i don't really understand my query. When i try to execute my program, error appear like this

> Warning: sqlsrv_has_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean
>   given

This is my code:

```
<?php
    session_start();

    try{
    include 'connection.php';

    $username = $_POST['user'];
    $password = $_POST['pass'];

    //check if login form is filled
    if(empty($_POST['user']) || empty($_POST['pass'])){
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Connection established.");   </script>';
     }
    //search for user and password in the database
    $query = "SELECT * FROM [Emkaandb].[dbo].[tbl_clientslogin] WHERE email='{$username}' AND .password='{$password}' AND active='1'";
    $result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query);
    if($result == true){
    die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(),true));
     }
      if(sqlsrv_has_rows($result) !=1){
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Invalid email or password.");  </script>';
    }else{
     while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result)){
        $_SESSION['name'] = $row['name'];

    }
    header("location: Profile.php");
    }

     }catch  (PDOException $e)
  {
    echo "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "
";
    die();
  }

?>
```

Comment: just in case you didn't know. sqlsrv functions has nothing to do with PDO functions. and thus there is very little use in catching PDOExceptions in this code.

Comment: In fact, you have to ask explicitly for error messages: [sqlsrv_errors()](http://php.net/sqlsrv_errors). Once you do you'll see that your SQL is invalid to begin with.

Comment: BTW, it seems your code allows universal login with the magic password `' OR 1=1--`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$result return resource set id ?

Comment: i can see if($result == true){
    die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(),true));
     } thats die () ? because $result always true...